# Android development application cannot install error for the new version

Tags: android, versioning, keystore, signing

I ve lost the signing keystore and now new release of my application gives the error "Application cannot install" while trying to update. Is there a way to change the error message that is shown to the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The user has to remove the version in order to install the new one.

Next time store your keystore with a service like Dropbox as well, so you cant lose it ;-)

Comment: +1 heard cases where people had to pull down the apps from the market bcos they lost the key to sign they updated version :P

Comment: Uh, I hope that wasn't a paid app :D